# Whats the best way to detect SPAM in PHP messages

Tags: php, mysql, spam, spam-prevention

I'm trying to fight the battle of users trying to contact other users and asking for money. They are typically from Nigeria or Ghana.

Several things I've tried are blocking these countries entirely upon signup based on their IP. I've also tried detecting similar message content and limiting the number of messages sent to 5 per day.

Are their any available PHP classes that handle this better or in a different way?

It is a daily battle to detect and remove these users based on messages sent.

Comment: why not run spamassassin and other dedicated filtering tools, rather than shuffling everything through php? Or are you trying to filter spam LEAVING your system via your scripts?

Comment: Are you trying to block them because you believe these are "bots" filling out your forms? Or actual humans?

Comment: Akismet is widely used by most wordpress blogs and it has multiple libraries (eg. a PHP5 library): http://akismet.com/development/

Comment: @Adam They are actual humans but they are solicting other members for money.

Comment: Are you using captcha?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I don't have a wordpress blog and it looks like they require a wordpress API key for the PHP class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best solution to anti-spam in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570367/best-solution-to-anti-spam-in-php)

Comment: Can you give us more context on your product? It sounds like you're running a message board of some kind.

Comment: These are internal messages sent between users. The site is more of a social networking site

Comment: What about forcing users to register before sending an email?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Detecting Spam**

Paul Graham lays out the theory behind a Bayesian filter that can filter out spam content:

http://www.paulgraham.com/spam.html  and 
http://paulgraham.com/better.html

Search for PHP code that can do Bayesian filtering on blocks of text.  Allow the readers of the messages to "mark the message as spam" and use that as input for the Bayesian filter.  Copy Gmail's user interface as much as possible so people know what to do.

**How Google uses technologies in Gmail to fight spam:**

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/10/how-gmail-blocks-spam.html

Comment: Messages to people usually are collections of words :D

Comment: +1 for the awesome articles you linked.

Comment: You sir, are an evil mastermind.  I am so using this.

Answer (score 3):

Use an external service like [Askimet](http://akismet.com/about/). It's free for personal use.

Comment: "users trying to contact other users" doesn't sound like personal use